# Windows 8.1 Setup, moving app from background processes to apps (task manager-foreground)

Tags: windows-8.1, formatting, task-manager, setup

I want to format my Windows 8.1, not the 1st time I do so I know how to do it, but this time while I was waiting for the % to finish, I think it was around 26% at that moment so I went to play a game (on the same pc) while I wait to finish and continue with it, but when I minimize the game my PC froze and I had to restart it from my CPU since I couldn't from the system even ctrl+alt+del didn't work.

When I restarted the PC and went to re-load the downloading/setup to try to format windows the program started running on background processes so I can't see the window I tried checking hidden icons so it could probably be there but not, it was later that I notice it was running on background I don't really know why and I really can't see if it's really working since it has been 3 hours and I haven't seen any notice that it will finish anytime since if I remember I think I had to choose some options after the 100%.

Is there a way to fix this and move the app to foreground or apps so I can view the window 'Windows Setup'

**`NOTE!!!!!`:** I purchased the digital version so I don't have the files on CD or USB it's directly from their web I suppose, not sure how that works tho.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't really understand your question... How do you play games on the same PC while formatting Windows?

Comment: I mean playing while I wait for windows to download... see image link http://i58.tinypic.com/160ubzl.png it's not my screenshot but it reflects where my PC froze when I was playing, after that downloading thing is where you choose if you stay with your files and that stuff but since I can't even see the window I can't choose anything. And then it comes everything I mention about noticing that windows setup was working as a background process after the PC reboot (FROM CPU) since I could't do it from the system.

Comment: What happens if you end the process in Task Manager and retry the format?